# If $a_n \rightarrow a$ Then $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \rightarrow a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

If $a_n \rightarrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then can we say that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \rightarrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?
If we consider $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$ as average of terms, it seems obvious intuitively. But how can I prove it rigorously?

My idea was followings:
Since $a_n \rightarrow a$, given arbitary $\epsilon>0$, there is some $N$ s.t. $n \geq N \implies \lvert a_n-a\rvert<\epsilon$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k-a\right\rvert & \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \lvert a_k-a\rvert + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=N+1}^{n} \lvert a_k-a\rvert \\ &\leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \lvert a_k-a\rvert + \frac{n-N-1}{n}\epsilon \\& \leq \frac{2}{n}A + \frac{n-N+1}{n}\epsilon
\end{align}
where $A = \sup a_n <\infty$ as $a_n$ converges.
Then by letting $n \rightarrow \infty$ gives
\begin{equation}
\left\lvert \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k-a\right\rvert \leq \epsilon
\end{equation}
for arbitary $\epsilon$, so our claim is proved.

Is there any non-rigorous part or wrong in my proof? (I'm a beginner at analysis.)
Thanks

Comment: Your proof looks fine. Also, it can be a direct result of Stolz-Cesaro theorem.

Comment: My only nitpick is $A$ should be defined as $\max(|a|, \sup |a_n|)$. Your result is also a special case of Stolz-Cesaro Theorem, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz–Cesàro_theorem#Applications_and_examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz–Cesàro_theorem#Applications_and_examples).

Comment: Don't forget to add "solution-verification" tag when asking to validate a proof! This question was asked quite a few times before, it could have been closed as a duplicate otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I'll be careful about that.

Comment: Just a minor detail but: if I'm not wrong, shouldn't it be $\frac{2NA}{n}$ because $\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k-a| \leq \sum_{k=1}^n (|a_k|+|a|) = \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k| + \sum_{k=1}^n |a| \leq 2A \sum_{k=1}^{n} 1 = 2AN$?

Comment: @Dunkelheit Oh, that's right. I missed $N$. thanks

Comment: @nyeon_22: The missing $N$ should be added. We also have $\frac{n-N}{n}\epsilon$. It's  recommended to write $A=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left| a_n\right|$ denoting *explicitly* the scope of $n$, since the meaning of $n$ here is not the same as the meaning of $n(\geq N)$ used above. Nevertheless good work (+1).